# how to return a value inside an interval, for a tag in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, return, setinterval

I have this code, and i want to port it into a tag in my reactJS app. What it's suppose to do is slowly update the lets to reveal my name. Kinda like it's being decrypted.

However it does not seem to return anything, the logic works, since the console.log inside the interval does what it needs to do. But anything outside the interval does not. Can someone help me understand how to get this to work for a html tag in my react app?

```
   <h3 className="center-align" id="my_name">
       {this.hackerLoad()}
   </h3>
//^^^^^^^ this is the small section i need to edit,
// i didn't want to add a bunch of non relevant code. this is inside my return(); 



   hackerLoad = () => {
        console.log("loaded");
        let hiddenName = [
            "Dwkuow Flexul",
            "Dwkuow Flexua",
            "Dwkuow Flexia",
            "Dwkuow Flecia",
            "Dwkuow Flrcia",
            "Dwkuow Farcia",
            "Dwkuow Garcia",
            "Dwkuoe Garcia",
            "Dwkupe Garcia",
            "Dwkipe Garcia",
            "Dwlipe Garcia",
            "Delipe Garcia",
            "Felipe Garcia",
        ];
        let i = 0;
        let name = "Dwkuow Flexul";
        const createDevName = setInterval(() => {
            i += 1;
            if (i > 12) {
                clearInterval(createDevName);
            }
            name = hiddenName[i];
            console.log(name);
        }, 500);

        return name;
    };
```

Comment: Just changing the `name` variable in your closure won't cause a rerender. You need to store the changing content of `name` in your component's state.

Comment: I'm really new at react, im not sure what you mean. I know that return name is not getting the actual name/being updated because it's not in the scope of the interval. but i am not sure on how to go about implementing it so that it generates in the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here is how you can make this work. The key thing to remember is that React components only rerender when either their props or their state change. Here is a working solution using state.

Change the relevant section of `render` to

```
<h3 className="center-align" id="my_name">
   {this.state.name}
</h3>
```

In the constructor, include `this.state ={name: "Dwkuow Flexul"}`

And move the name updating logic to `componentDidMount`, using `setState` to update the name:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let hiddenName = [
        "Dwkuow Flexul",
        "Dwkuow Flexua",
        "Dwkuow Flexia",
        "Dwkuow Flecia",
        "Dwkuow Flrcia",
        "Dwkuow Farcia",
        "Dwkuow Garcia",
        "Dwkuoe Garcia",
        "Dwkupe Garcia",
        "Dwkipe Garcia",
        "Dwlipe Garcia",
        "Delipe Garcia",
        "Felipe Garcia",
    ];
    let i = 0;
    let name = "Dwkuow Flexul";
    const createDevName = setInterval(() => {
        i += 1;
        if (i > 12) {
            clearInterval(createDevName);
        }
        this.setState({name: hiddenName[i]});
    }, 500);
};
```

You should also clear the interval in `componentWillUnmount`, to avoid memory leaks in case of the component getting destroyed early. (Which will need the interval id to be moved from the local scope of `componentDidMount` to a property of the entire component.)

Comment: That did it thank you. I understand most of the code there and did some googling to understand the stuff i did not quite get. I was not even aware of stuff like componentDidMount! So i'll look into all that to have a better understanding. The one thing i don't quite get is why i need a constructor?

Comment: You initialise the state inside the constructor, so that you get the correct thing on the initial render.